# Redis creating dump.rdb in /tmp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

Using redis and sidekiq for background processing, and creating jobs on sidekiq from different server rather than where sidekiq is running.

`dir` for redis data is set as `/var/lib/redis` which redis was pointing to initially. But in the middle of nowhere, `dir` got set to `/tmp`. Now, `dump.rdb` is getting created in `/tmp` which get resets at anytime and data gets lost.

Some of the configuration from `redis.conf` is follow:

```
daemonize yes
pidfile /var/run/redis/redis-server.pid
port 6379
logfile /var/log/redis/redis-server.log
databases 16
save 300 10
dir /var/lib/redis
dbfilename dump.rdb
#bind 127.0.0.1
```

What can be causing redis to create `dump.rdb` in `/tmp` ?

Comment: If your Redis is unprotected and accessible to the outside, anyone can charge the `dir` configuration directive... Is it?

Comment: That might be the case @ItamarHaber, as the behavior of changing `dir` to `/tmp` is unpredictable. I'll set `bind` configuration to specific IP and let you know.

Comment: Burn the server, and set up a new one - you may have been compromised far more seriously than just a configuration change

Comment: thanks for the tip @ItamarHaber, we are looking into it. 
Also, no changes are made to `dir` since yesterday, so it might the case that someone was accessing it. Could you add that as a answer so that I can accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your Redis server's version and its configuration, it could be that what you are describing is the result of unauthorized access to your database.

If your database is accessible to the outside world and isn't properly secured, anyone can issue a `CONFIG SET dir` directive to it (or any other command for that matter).

For a better grasp of the potential damage, see this illustrative post by Redis' author: http://antirez.com/news/96